# Spring Integration Stored Proc Outboud Gateway Call for In and Out Parameter(INDEX BY TABLE)

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-integration

I am trying to execute a oracle stored proc from spring integration stored-proc-outbound-gateway

Bellow is the context

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
    id="checkSlotToDelete" data-source="dataSource" request-channel="slotRequestChannel"
    is-function="false" reply-channel="replyChannel"
    ignore-column-meta-data="true"
    stored-procedure-name="PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT.PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT"
    expect-single-result="false">
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="USER_NUMIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="STORE_NUMIN" direction="IN" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="ZONE_NUMIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="SLOT_NUMIN" direction="IN" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="RANGE_COUNTIN" direction="IN" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="APP_PARAMIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LIST" direction="OUT" type="OTHER"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="USER_NUMIN" expression="payload.USER_NUMIN" />
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="STORE_NUMIN" expression="payload.STORE_NUMIN" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="ZONE_NUMIN" expression="payload.ZONE_NUMIN" />
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="SLOT_NUMIN" expression="payload.SLOT_NUMIN" />
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="RANGE_COUNTIN" expression="payload.RANGE_COUNTIN" />
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="APP_PARAMIN" value="CREATE" />
    <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="P_LIST" row-mapper="singleRowMapper"/>
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Bellow is the proc defination

```
    PROCEDURE PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT
       (
        USER_NUMIN    IN    VARCHAR2,
        STORE_NUMIN   IN    NUMBER,
        ZONE_NUMIN    IN    VARCHAR2,
        SLOT_NUMIN    IN    NUMBER,
        RANGE_COUNTIN IN    NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
        APP_PARAMIN   IN    VARCHAR2,
        P_LIST        OUT   T_LIST )
```

And T_LIST is defined as

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT
 IS
TYPE T_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT (USER_NUMIN IN VARCHAR2,STORE_NUMIN IN NUMBER,ZONE_NUMIN IN VARCHAR2,SLOT_NUMIN IN NUMBER,RANGE_COUNTIN IN     NUMBER DEFAULT 0 ,APP_PARAMIN IN VARCHAR2,P_LIST OUT T_LIST);
 END PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT;
```

Now when I am executing the program, Getting the following log.

```
**org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall  - The following parameters are used for call {call PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT.PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} 
with: {SLOT_NUMIN=17, ZONE_NUMIN=1, APP_PARAMIN=CREATE, STORE_NUMIN=5, RANGE_COUNTIN=1, USER_NUMIN=MyUser}**
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Calling stored procedure [{call PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT.PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [MyUser], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [5], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 2
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [1], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [17], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type 2
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 5, parameter value [1], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type 2
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 6, parameter value [CREATE], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12


11418 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-1] [2014-10-31 14:52:24,393] WARN  org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway  - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT.PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:473)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:370)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.asda.connect.utility.filter.RESTCorsDemoResponseFilter.doFilter(RESTCorsDemoResponseFilter.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call PKG_CONNECT_LOC_MNGMNT.PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:378)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:341)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcExecutor.executeStoredProcedureInternal(StoredProcExecutor.java:328)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcExecutor.executeStoredProcedure(StoredProcExecutor.java:297)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(StoredProcOutboundGateway.java:60)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:223)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:200)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:344)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:304)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:295)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.asda.connect.locationmanagement.service.CheckServiceActivator.checkValidRequest(CheckServiceActivator.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:122)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:44)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:159)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75)
    ... 40 more
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PR_CREATE_RANGE_OR_DELETE_SLOT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1041)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.execute(CachedPreparedStatement.java:297)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.execute(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1121)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue that `advanced Oracle type` isn't `CURSOR` as you try to get deal with it using `returning-resultset`.

First of all you should get rid of it and use the `return-type` feature introduced since Spring Integration 3.0:

```
...
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LIST" direction="OUT" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).ARRAY}" type-name="T_LIST" return-type="sqlReturnArray"/>
...

<bean id="sqlReturnArray" class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlReturnArray"/>
```

Where the last one is from [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html).

I haven't use Oracle for a long time already, hance I might not be right for the correct `SqlReturnType` impl, but looks like your `T_LIST` is just an array of `VARCHAR2`.

For this problem making  T_LIST  out of the package will solved the wrong number/type of argument issue.

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan

I made the changes.. but getting another exception..
   unsupported network datatype or representation

Comment: M-m-m. But you show there the same StackTrace. Try to remove `type="VARCHAR"` from your param definitions.

Comment: Removed all the type attributes from param definations ...but still same error

Comment: Try to name it just like `type="ARRAY"`. If doesn't help, I will suggest you to try to achieve the good result of that stored propcedure call just with raw JDBC. When it will be ready you can return to me for the help how to convert it to the Spring Integration adapter. I used `ARRAY` as an input parameter and the had been needed to specify those types together with `SHEME_NAME` and they was outside of package. From other side why just don't return CURSOR as a `select` from that `T_LIST`?

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan 
 I have changed the T_LIST out of the packege, now the proc if executing without the type exception.

But now fetching issue for oracle jar.
 java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.ARRAY cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY

One from the application another from jboss.

Comment: The classloader issue. How about do not use application scope one? Make that dependency as `provided`?

Comment: Made dependency as provided, while deploying the application .. exception thrown   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 0): Type cannot be found 'oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes'

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan
 I made the dependency as provided and added jboss dependency in MANIFEST file, now it is working properly.
Thank you very much...

I would like to edit your first answer for future reference, if you don't have any issue.

Comment: Great! I'm glad to see that you fixed that. No problem, if add a useful info to my answer!